# Application main NSMenu not responding without window reactivation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenu

I'm trying a minimalistic Cocoa app as described in [this page](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html)
using code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>;
int main ()
{
    [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
    id menubar = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
    id appMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem new] autorelease];
    [menubar addItem:appMenuItem];
    [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
    id appMenu = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
    id appName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];
    id quitTitle = [@"Quit " stringByAppendingString:appName];
    id quitMenuItem = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:quitTitle
        action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"] autorelease];
    [appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
    [appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
    id window = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200)
        styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO]
            autorelease];
    [window cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:NSMakePoint(20,20)];
    [window setTitle:appName];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [NSApp run];
    return 0;
}
```

My issue is, that the application menu is not responding until I reactivate its window (activating another app and then clicking back to my app window).

Any idea why and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AppKit is still in your app's startup phase when you're attempting to call `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];`.
The correct way to do it is to handle it through `NSApplicationDelegate`:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic, class, readonly) AppDelegate* sharedInstance;
@end
@implementation AppDelegate
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static AppDelegate *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [AppDelegate new];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
}
@end

int main ()
{
    [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate = [AppDelegate sharedInstance];
    [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
    id menubar = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
    id appMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem new] autorelease];
    [menubar addItem:appMenuItem];
    [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
    id appMenu = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
    id appName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];
    id quitTitle = [@"Quit " stringByAppendingString:appName];
    id quitMenuItem = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:quitTitle
        action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"] autorelease];
    [appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
    [appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
    id window = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200)
        styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO]
            autorelease];
    [window cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:NSMakePoint(20,20)];
    [window setTitle:appName];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    [NSApp run];
    return 0;
}
```

As a bonus the delegate's `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {`  will get invoked before your:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
});
```

hinting it's the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... I found the solution... I must replace

```
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

with:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    });
```

I don't know why, but it works.

Comment: If you're calling async on main while you're already on main, you're basically telling the program to finish all tasks on the main thread first, until nothing is left. Once a gap comes up, this code will be executed. Since the ui update loop is one big function that need to be called and finished before the application actually updates itself to the right state, doing this will put the code after every required changes has been done